# How to stop webviews in a list from refreshing when the list is scrolled down?

Tags: android

I have web views in a list. Every time i scroll down the list, the webviews refreshes.
How do i prevent the webviews form refreshing?
I am using the listview to show the pictures and text from an online database.
I am using webview to show these pictures.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
FlyOutContainer root;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
private static final String RATING_URL = "http://sanoawaz.orgfree.com/rating.php";
private static final String TAG_POSTS = "posts";
private final String READ_COMMENTS_URL = "http://sanoawaz.orgfree.com/comments2.php";
List<codeLeanChapter> codeLeanChaptersList = new ArrayList<codeLeanChapter>();
String sideMenu[] = { "Place New Report", "My Reports", "Short By",
        "Water", "Road", "Electricity", "Construstion",
        "Waste Disposal and Electricity", "Nearby Reports", "Others",
        "Settings" };
FlyOutContainer fly;
int l = 9;
JSONArray mComments = null;
public static String filename = "SanoAawazPref";
SharedPreferences sanoaawazpref;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

    this.root = (FlyOutContainer) this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.newmenulayout, null);
    this.setContentView(root);

    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
            R.layout.actiobarlayout);
    sanoaawazpref = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
    String username = sanoaawazpref.getString("username", "not got");
    Log.d("check", username);

    ImageButton b = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.viewtoggleib);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            toggleMenu(root);
        }
    });

    aa = new SideMenuAdapter();
    typesofreport = new TypeOfReportAdapter();
    ListView sidelist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.newlistView1);
    sidelist.setAdapter(aa);
    ListView typeslist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.newlistView3);
    typeslist.setAdapter(typesofreport);

    typeslist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            sanoaawazpref = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sanoaawazpref.edit();
            Intent ouinttent;
            switch (arg2) {

            case 0:

                editor.putInt("reptype11", 0);
                editor.commit();
                ouinttent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAINACTIVITY");
                startActivity(ouinttent);
                break;

            case 1:

                editor.putInt("reptype11", 1);
                editor.commit();
                ouinttent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAINACTIVITY");
                startActivity(ouinttent);
                break;
            case 2:

                editor.putInt("reptype11", 2);
                editor.commit();
                ouinttent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAINACTIVITY");
                startActivity(ouinttent);
            case 3:

                editor.putInt("reptype11", 3);
                editor.commit();
                ouinttent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAINACTIVITY");
                startActivity(ouinttent);
            case 4:

                editor.putInt("reptype11", 4);
                editor.commit();
                ouinttent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAINACTIVITY");
                startActivity(ouinttent);
            case 5:

                editor.putInt("reptype11", 5);
                editor.commit();
                ouinttent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAINACTIVITY");
                startActivity(ouinttent);

            }

        }
    });

    // OnclickListner for the sidemenu
    sidelist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (arg2) {
            case 0:
                Intent ourintent = new Intent(
                        "android.intent.action.NEWREPORT");
                startActivity(ourintent);
                break;
            case 1:
                Intent ouintent = new Intent(
                        "android.intent.action.PORTSSTOREDINPHONE");
                startActivity(ouintent);
                break;

            }
        }
    }

    );

    new LoadComments().execute();
    // for home list, adapter initialization and linking with list

}

public void getlistready() {

    chapterListAdapter = new CodeLearnAdapter();
    ListView codeLearnLessons = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.newlistView2);
    codeLearnLessons.setAdapter(chapterListAdapter);

    // Onitemclicklistner for the home page list
    codeLearnLessons.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

            codeLeanChapter chapter = chapterListAdapter
                    .getCodeLearnChapter(arg2);

            Dialog d = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            d.setTitle("Record Added Successfully");
            d.setContentView(R.layout.showindividualstoredreports);

            d.show();

        }
    });

}

// ll
public class codeLeanChapter {
    String chapterName;
    String chapterDescription;
    String chapterPostId;
    String chapterrating;
    Bitmap chapterPic;
}

public class sidemen {
    String itemname;
    Bitmap itemphoto;
}

public class typesofrp {
    String itemname1;
    Bitmap itemphoto1;
}

SideMenuAdapter aa;

public class SideMenuAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    List<sidemen> sideList = getDataForSideListView();

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return sideList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public sidemen getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return sideList.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

        if (arg1 == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            arg1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listlayout3, arg2, false);
        }

        TextView chapterName = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        ImageView iv = (ImageView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        sidemen side = sideList.get(arg0);
        iv.setImageBitmap(side.itemphoto);

        chapterName.setText(side.itemname);

        return arg1;
    }

    public sidemen getCodeLearnChapter(int position) {
        return sideList.get(position);
    }

}

public List<sidemen> getDataForSideListView() {
    List<sidemen> codeLeanChaptersList = new ArrayList<sidemen>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

        sidemen chapter = new sidemen();
        if (i == 0) {
            InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(
                    R.drawable.newreport);
            Bitmap pic = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            chapter.itemname = "Place New Report";
            chapter.itemphoto = pic;
        } else {
            InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(
                    R.drawable.myreports);
            Bitmap pic = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            chapter.itemname = "View My Reports";
            chapter.itemphoto = pic;
        }

        codeLeanChaptersList.add(chapter);
    }

    return codeLeanChaptersList;

}

TypeOfReportAdapter typesofreport;

public class TypeOfReportAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    List<typesofrp> typeLists = getDataForTypeListView();

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return typeLists.size();
    }

    @Override
    public typesofrp getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return typeLists.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

        if (arg1 == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            arg1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listlayout3, arg2, false);
        }

        TextView chapterName = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        ImageView iv = (ImageView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        typesofrp rep = typeLists.get(arg0);
        iv.setImageBitmap(rep.itemphoto1);

        chapterName.setText(rep.itemname1);

        return arg1;
    }

    public typesofrp getCodeLearnChapter(int position) {
        return typeLists.get(position);
    }

}

public List<typesofrp> getDataForTypeListView() {
    List<typesofrp> TypeListss = new ArrayList<typesofrp>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        typesofrp chapter = new typesofrp();
        switch (i) {
        case 0:
            InputStream is11 = getResources().openRawResource(
                    R.drawable.water);
            Bitmap pic11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is11);
            chapter.itemname1 = "All";
            chapter.itemphoto1 = pic11;
            break;

        case 1:
            InputStream is0 = getResources().openRawResource(
                    R.drawable.water);
            Bitmap pic0 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is0);
            chapter.itemname1 = "Water";
            chapter.itemphoto1 = pic0;
            break;
        case 2:
            InputStream is1 = getResources().openRawResource(
                    R.drawable.road);
            Bitmap pic1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is1);
            chapter.itemname1 = "Road";
            chapter.itemphoto1 = pic1;
            break;
        case 3:
            InputStream is2 = getResources().openRawResource(
                    R.drawable.electricity);
            Bitmap pic2 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is2);
            chapter.itemname1 = "Electricity";
            chapter.itemphoto1 = pic2;
            break;
        case 4:
            InputStream is3 = getResources().openRawResource(
                    R.drawable.constructions);
            Bitmap pic3 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is3);
            chapter.itemname1 = "Construction";
            chapter.itemphoto1 = pic3;
            break;
        case 5:
            InputStream is4 = getResources().openRawResource(
                    R.drawable.waste);
            Bitmap pic4 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is4);
            chapter.itemname1 = "Waste Disposal";
            chapter.itemphoto1 = pic4;
            break;

        }
        TypeListss.add(chapter);
    }
    return TypeListss;
}

CodeLearnAdapter chapterListAdapter;

public class CodeLearnAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    List<codeLeanChapter> codeLeanChapterList = codeLeanChaptersList;

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return codeLeanChapterList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public codeLeanChapter getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return codeLeanChapterList.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

        if (arg1 == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            arg1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listmenulayout, arg2, false);
        }

        TextView chapterName = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView chapterDesc = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        WebView wv = (WebView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        codeLeanChapter chapter = codeLeanChapterList.get(arg0);

        chapterName.setText(chapter.chapterName);
        chapterDesc.setText(chapter.chapterDescription);

        ImageButton imgb = (ImageButton) arg1
                .findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

        imgb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Dialog edt;
                edt = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                edt.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                edt.setContentView(R.layout.viewinginvrecordsinmainactivity);
                WebView wv = (WebView) edt.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
                wv.loadUrl("http://browser.gameguyz.com/upload/images/139972258802.png");
                wv.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);         

                TextView tvreportname = (TextView) edt
                        .findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                TextView tvreportname1 = (TextView) edt
                        .findViewById(R.id.textView6);
                TextView tvreportname2 = (TextView) edt
                        .findViewById(R.id.textView7);
                codeLeanChapter chapter = codeLeanChapterList.get(arg0);
                ImageButton imgbut = (ImageButton) edt
                        .findViewById(R.id.like);
                imgbut.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(final View arg1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Log.d("aa", "fine untille .execute");
                        new AttemptRating().execute(arg0);

                    }

                });
                tvreportname.setText(chapter.chapterName);
                tvreportname1.setText(chapter.chapterDescription
                        + chapter.chapterPostId);
                tvreportname2.setText(chapter.chapterrating);
                edt.show();
            }

        });

        wv.loadUrl("https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-fP6fXxpvvYg/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/qoi2qTn2iMs/photo.jpg");
        wv.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        wv.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        wv.setInitialScale(35);
        WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        wv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return true;
            }

        });

        return arg1;
    }

    public codeLeanChapter getCodeLearnChapter(int position) {
        return codeLeanChapterList.get(position);
    }


}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void toggleMenu(View v) {
    this.root.toggleMenu();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public class LoadComments extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // we will develop this method in version 2
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject jsoni = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(READ_COMMENTS_URL);
        sanoaawazpref = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
        int reptype = sanoaawazpref.getInt("reptype11", 0);

        try {
            if (reptype == 0) {
                mComments = jsoni.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);
                l = mComments.length();

                for (int i = 0; i < mComments.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject c = mComments.getJSONObject(i);
                    codeLeanChapter chapter = new codeLeanChapter();
                    chapter.chapterName = c.getString("username");
                    chapter.chapterDescription = c.getString("discreption");
                    chapter.chapterPostId = c.getString("post_id");
                    chapter.chapterrating = c.getString("rating");
                    codeLeanChaptersList.add(chapter);
                    Log.d("good yetako ho yo chai", "");
                }
            } else {
                mComments = jsoni.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);
                l = mComments.length();

                for (int i = 0; i < mComments.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject c = mComments.getJSONObject(i);
                    codeLeanChapter chapter = new codeLeanChapter();
                    if (c.getInt("reptype") == reptype) {
                        chapter.chapterName = c.getString("username");
                        chapter.chapterDescription = c
                                .getString("location");
                        chapter.chapterPostId = c.getString("post_id");
                        codeLeanChaptersList.add(chapter);
                    }

                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        getlistready();
        Log.d("wkakkaka", "" + l);
    }
}

class AttemptRating extends AsyncTask<Integer , Integer, String> {

    boolean failure = false;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please Wait ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... numberoflistitem) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<codeLeanChapter> codeLeanChapterList = codeLeanChaptersList;
        int xxl = numberoflistitem[0];
        codeLeanChapter chapter = codeLeanChapterList.get(xxl);

        String postid = chapter.chapterPostId;


        try {
            sanoaawazpref = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
            String username = sanoaawazpref.getString("username", "not got");
            Log.d("", username);
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new

            ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("postid", postid));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rateby", Integer.toString(1)));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");
            // getting product details by making
            // HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(RATING_URL,
                    "POST", params);

            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

            // json success tag
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("Register Successful!", json.toString());



            } else {
                Log.d("Registration Failure!", json.getString

                (TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;


    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (file_url != null) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}
```

xml for the individual items in the list

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/reportedby"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/webView1"
    android:text="Reported By:"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/reportedby"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/location"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:maxLength="10" 
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/webView1"
        android:text="Description:"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/cloudview"
        android:background="@null"
         />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Where's the list? Could you post the complete code and xml layout of your activity?

Comment: i have added the class and xml for individual list items.

Comment: i trying to display a picture from web in my list. Each list item contains 2 text views and a web view.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using web view for loading image you could use just an ImageView and then use an AsynTask to load image from url in background and use in ImageView on completion.You can also use 
[Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)
library to do all that for you.